# Statsoc style package giving table positioning problems

Tags: latex

I am formating a paper in statsoc style. I inserted a table. But it moves to the top of the page even though it should be placed in the middle of the page after some text.

I tried using float package with table options [H],[H!], [h]. But that results in printing [H] (or whatever the option i type) before caption  like this:

[H] Table 1: table_caption

Please help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Within the **statsoc.cls**, you need to change def\fps@table{***tbp***} to \def\fps@table{***htbp***}.

Comment: This works well. thanks @Ana-Maria Dobre